# OpenMP and MPI Literature

Tags: mpi, openmp

New to both OpenMP and MPI.

Could you guys help me with some links where I could find some info regarding both of them. 
Haven't read anything that is related to OpenMp and MPI.

Comment: Even just the tag wikis here for MPI and OpenMP list several suggested references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both standards are actually pretty nice to read. [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/wp/openmp-specifications/) and [MPI](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.0/mpi30-report.pdf) specifications are both available electronically and provide examples and explanations. There are also online courses available, for example at the [HLRS website](https://fs.hlrs.de/projects/par/par_prog_ws/).
The standard introductory book on MPI might be [Using MPI](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/usingmpi2/index.html) by Gropp, Lusk and Thakur. The OpenMP website [lists some suitable books](http://openmp.org/wp/resources/#Books).

Comment: While the MPI standard is actually readable by non-implementers, the newer OpenMP specifications are quite tough reads. And in version 4.0 the examples are no longer part of the main document.